# Official Java excercize solution doesn't work... what I am doing wrong?

Tags: java, arraylist, contains, indexof

atm I am doing a Java excerzise which is about comparing an integer with all elements of an ArrayList. The solution according to the book should be a comparison with "int index = ArrayList.indexOf(comparisonValue);" and "index >= 0".
But for me, it doesn't work. I also read that "indexof" only checks the first position of an ArrayList. But when this is true, why is this marked as the correct solution in my book?

Maybe I got an error. Here is my code, thx :)

```
ArrayList<Integer> tiplist = new ArrayList<Integer>(20);
int des = 0;
int limit = 20;
int tipc = 0;
int index = tiplist.indexOf(tip);
    
    //program loop:
    while (des == 0 && tipc < limit) {
        tip = 6;   //I made it easy to read, normally the number is generated   
        tipc++;   //tip count
        if (tipc > 1) {   //if it is not the first tip
```

**That isn't working:**

```
        if (index >= 0) {
            System.out.println("Nothing new");

        }
```

**But that one does, although I read that "contains" also uses "indexof":**

```
        if (tiplist.contains(tip) == true) {
            System.out.println("Nothing new");
        }
```

Last lines...

```
  }
            tiplist.add(tip);
    // -->do something
}
```

Comment: In `if (index >= 0) {`, `index` isn't updated on each iteration of the loop, so it uses the value you calculated before the loop. Whilst `if (tiplist.contains(tip) == true) {` uses `indexOf`, it re-evaluates the `indexOf` on each loop iteration.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please provide a [mre]? Also, it would be great if you could edit to remove chat terminology like "thx" or "atm" :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `int index = tiplist.indexOf(tip);` just after
`tip = 6;   //I made it easy to read, normally the number is generated`

In your case value is assigned to `index` before it's calculated/*generated*, hence using default value probably you are setting before.

Answer (score -1):

You can't find the index of tip in tipList until you know what the tip is and you've filled in the list.